# Why does my script file turn into an exact copy of my index file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to run my site on localhost with Node.js. It downloads, but the script specified in my index file does not work. Looking at the page sources it seems that my script file has turned into an exact copy of my index file. What could cause that?

Here's my code:

```
const http = require('http')
const fs = require('fs')
const port = 3000

const server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html'})
    fs.readFile('index.html', function(error, data) {
        if (error) {
            res.writeHead(404)
            res.write('Error: File not found')
        } else {
            res.write(data)
        }
        res.end()
    })
})

server.listen(port, function(error) {
    if (error) {
        console.log('Something went wrong', error)
    } else {
        console.log('Server is listening on port ' + port)
    }
})
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    
    
    <body>
        <h1>Hi</h1>

        <div id="words">*</div>

        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
words.innerHTML += "1";
```

Comment: That's pretty common when your frontend app has a catch-all, because is expected to handle 404 errors.  How are you handling routing? Could you share that, along with your webpack or rollup config?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any logic to return different responses (e.g. based on the requested URL), so your server always responds with the `index.html` document, even when other resources are requested (like your script).

You can implement the logic yourself, or you can use existing software to do it. A very commonly used one is called [`express`](https://expressjs.com/).